# Вывод массива в cardview

Tags: java, android, cardview

Получаю данные из JSON страницы, записываю их в массив, при выводе в cardview ничего не выводит (белый экран). Смотрю по logcat данные в массиве есть.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

**ObjectsFragment**

```
public class ObjectsFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "ObjectsFragment";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private List<Object> mObjects;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FetchData process = new FetchData();
    process.execute();
}

public static ObjectsFragment newInstance() {
    return new ObjectsFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_objects, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    ObjectAdapter adapter = new ObjectAdapter(mObjects, getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    return v;
}
```

**ObjectAdapter**

```
public class ObjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ObjectAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Object> mObjectList;
private Context mContext;

public ObjectAdapter(List<Object> objects, Context context) {

    this.mObjectList = objects;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_objects, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ObjectAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Object object = mObjectList.get(position);
    holder.mName.setText(object.getName());
    holder.mAddress.setText(object.getAddress());
    holder.mSalesPlan.setText(object.getSalesPlan());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mObjectList != null) {
        return mObjectList.size();
    }
    return 0;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mName;
    public TextView mAddress;
    public TextView mCurrentSales;
    public TextView mSalesPlan;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        mAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_text_view);
        mCurrentSales = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.current_sales_text_view);
        mSalesPlan = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sales_plan_text_view);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:
1. В `ObjectAdapter` добавьте метод

```
public void setData(List<Object> data){
 mObjectList = data;
}
```

2. В `FetchData`(судя по всему это наследник `AsyncTask`?) переопределите `onPostExecute` так

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Object> newData){
     adapter.setData(newData);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

При этом третьим параметром `AsyncTask` должен быть `List<Object>` и это же должен возвращать `doInBackground`. `adapter` - это тот, что создан в `ObjectFragment`, его нужно сделать доступным в классе `FetchData`

Comment: все сделал, кроме последнего, как в классе [FetchData] вызвать adapter из [ObjectFragment] ?

Comment: Если это отдельный класс, то, наверное, только через конструктор. Создать конструктор с параметром `ObjectAdapter adapter` и передать туда адаптер при создании: `FetchData process = new FetchData(adapter);`

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что это хорошая практика, в плане возможной утечки памяти, но должно работать.

Comment: правда лучше будет все это в один класс объединить, и все отлично работает, спасибо тебе большое !

Answer (score 1):

Данные в адаптере у вас пусты. Вы пустой список отображаете и параллельно скачиваете инфу из сети. После завершения загрузки вы её не передаёте в адаптер и не уведомляете его о изменениях в данных.